# Another binomial coefficients sum: $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n-k\choose k}\frac {(-1)^k}{n-k}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Is there a closed form of the sum $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n-k\choose k}\frac {(-1)^k}{n-k}$$?

I cannot even guess what the sum will be. (We assume, here, that $i\choose j$=0 if $i < j$.)

Comment: Are you sure that is supposed to be ${n-k\choose k}$? Because when $k > \frac{1}{2}n$, ${n-k\choose k} = 0$

Comment: For $n\ge2$, we notice that $n\cdot S(n)$ forms the cycle of length six, $(-1,-2,-1,~1,2,1)$. If the $(-1)^k$ were absent, then for $n\ge1$ we'd have $n\cdot S'(n)$ forming a Fibonacci-like sequence, whose first two terms are $1$ and $3$.

Comment: Yes, here, we assume that $i\choose j$=0 if $i <j$.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha doesn't seem to want to simplify it. That tends to be a red flag that it might be in it's simplest form.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k%3D0+to+n-1+BinomialCoefficient(n-k%2C+k)&f1=BinomialCoefficient(n-k%2C+k)(-1)%5Ek%2F(n-k)&f=Sum.sumfunction_BinomialCoefficient(n-k%2C+k)(-1)%5Ek%2F(n-k)&f2=0&f=Sum.sumlowerlimit%5Cu005f0&f3=n-1&f=Sum.sumupperlimit2%5Cu005fn-1&a=*FVarOpt.1-_**-.***Sum.sumvariable---.*--) Alternatively, it's current form could just be too complex for it to bother with.

Comment: @Axoren: I've added an answer which might be of interest to you. Regards,

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1306605/ & http://math.stackexchange.com/q/121407/

Answer (score 3):

> The following is valid for $n\geq 1$
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n-k\choose k}\frac {(-1)^k}{n-k}=
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{2}{n}(-1)^n&n\equiv 0 \pmod{3}\\
> \frac{1}{n}(-1)^{n-1}&otherwise
> \end{cases}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

We will show the validity of (1) in two steps. At first we derive a generating function for the binomial expression. In the second step we extract the coefficients and show they correspond with the RHS of (1).

> **Step 1:** Generating functions
>
> The binomial expression in (1) can be written as
>
> \begin{align*}
> \binom{n-k}{k}\frac{1}{n-k}=\frac{1}{n}\left(\binom{n-k}{k}+\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}\right)
> \end{align*}
>
> and we derive two generating functions for the binomial expressions on the RHS.
>
> Let's consider the formal power series
>   \begin{align*}
> A(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kt^k
> \end{align*}

Similar to *[Euler's series transformation formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730885/how-prove-this-sum-sum-n-1-infty-binom2nn-frac-1n-1h-n14n/741969#741969)*

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-t}A\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a_k\right)t^n
\end{align*}

which provides us with a generating function for $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a_k$, we consider the transformation $\frac{1}{1-t}A\left(\frac{t^2}{1-t}\right)$.

> We obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{1-t}A\left(\frac{t^2}{1-t}\right)&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kt^{2k}(1-t)^{-(k+1)}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kt^{2k}\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\binom{-(k+1)}{l}(-t)^l\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kt^{2k}\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\binom{k+l}{l}(-t)^l\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{{2k+l=n}\atop{k,l\geq 0}}\binom{k+l}{l}a_k\right)t^n\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\binom{n-k}{n-2k}a_k\right)t^n\tag{5}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\binom{n-k}{k}a_k\right)t^n\tag{6}\\
> \end{align*}

**Comment:**

- In (2) we use the series expansion of the *[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*
- In (3) we use the identity $\binom{r}{s}=\binom{-r+s-1}{s}(-1)^s$
- In (4) we multiply the series
- In (5) we replace $l$ with $n-2k$.

> Next we obtain a generating function $B(t)$ by setting $a_k=(-1)^k$ in $A(t)$
>
> \begin{align*}
> B(t)=\frac{1}{1+t}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nt^n
> \end{align*}
>
> Since 
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{1-t}B\left(\frac{t^2}{1-t}\right)=\frac{1}{1-t}\frac{1}{1+\frac{t^2}{1-t}}=\frac{1}{1-t+t^2}
> \end{align*}
>
> we get from (6) the following identity
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\binom{n-k}{k}(-1)^k\right)t^n
> =\frac{1}{1-t+t^2}\tag{7}
> \end{align*}

In an analogous manner we obtain

\begin{align*}
A\left(\frac{t^2}{1-t}\right)&=a_0+\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\left(\frac{t^2}{1-t}\right)^k\\
&=\cdots\\
&=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}a_k\right)t^n
\end{align*}

> and get
>
> \begin{align*}
> B\left(\frac{t^2}{1-t}\right)&=\frac{1}{1+\frac{t^2}{1-t}}=\frac{1-t}{1-t+t^2}\\
> &=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}(-1)^k\right)t^n\tag{8}
> \end{align*}

In the following we use the  *[coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216)* operator $[t^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $t^n$ of the series.

> We can now put (7) and (8) together and derive
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} &{n-k\choose k}\frac {(-1)^k}{n-k}=\frac{1}{n}[t^n]\left(\frac{1}{1-t}B\left(\frac{t^2}{1-t}\right)+B\left(\frac{t^2}{1-t}\right)\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{n}[t^n]\left(\frac{1}{1-t+t^2}+\frac{1-t}{1-t+t^2}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{n}[t^n]\frac{2-t}{1-t+t^2}\tag{9}\\
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> **Step 2:** Coefficient extraction
>
> In order to find the coefficient of (9) we consider at first $\frac{1}{1-t+t^2}$ and show
>
> The following is valid
>   \begin{align*}
> [t^n]\frac{1}{1-t+t^2}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\sin\left((n+1)\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\qquad\qquad n\geq 0\tag{10}
> \end{align*}

Let $t_0,t_1$ denote the zeros of the polynomial $1-t+t^2$. Partial fraction decomposition gives
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(t-t_0)(t-t_1)}&=\frac{1}{t_0-t_1}\left(\frac{1}{t-t_1}-\frac{1}{t-t_0}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{t_0-t_1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{{t_0}^{k+1}}-\frac{1}{t_1^{k+1}}\right)t^k
\end{align*}
Since 
\begin{align*}
t_{0,1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1\pm i\sqrt{3}\right)=e^{\pm i\frac{\pi}{3}}
\end{align*}
and $t_0-t_1=i\sqrt{3}$ we obtain for $n\geq 0$
\begin{align*}
[t^n]\frac{1}{(t-t_0)(t-t_1)}&=\frac{1}{{(t_0t_1)}^{n+1}}\frac{t_0^{n+1}-t_1^{n+1}}{t_0-t_1}\\
&=\frac{e^{i(n+1)\frac{\pi}{3}}-e^{-i(n+1)\frac{\pi}{3}}}{i\sqrt{3}}\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\sin\left((n+1)\frac{\pi}{3}\right)
\end{align*}
and the claim (10) follows.

> Since we need the coefficient $[t^n]\frac{2-t}{1-t+t^2}$ we show the following is valid
>   \begin{align*}
> [t^n]\frac{2-t}{1-t+t^2}=2\cos\left(n\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\qquad\qquad n\geq 0\tag{11}
> \end{align*}

Using (10) we obtain

\begin{align*}
[t^n]\frac{2-t}{1-t+t^2}&=\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}\sin\left((n+1)\frac{\pi}{3}\right)
-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\sin\left(n\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\\
&=\frac{2e^{i(n+1)\frac{\pi}{3}}-2e^{-i(n+1)\frac{\pi}{3}}}{i\sqrt{3}}-
\frac{e^{in\frac{\pi}{3}}-e^{-in\frac{\pi}{3}}}{i\sqrt{3}}\\
&=-\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}\left(e^{in\frac{\pi}{3}}\left(2e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}-1\right)
-e^{-in\frac{\pi}{3}}\left(2e^{-i\frac{\pi}{3}}-1\right)\right)\\
&=-\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}\left(e^{in\frac{\pi}{3}}i\sqrt{3}
-e^{-in\frac{\pi}{3}}(-i\sqrt{3})\right)\\
&=e^{in\frac{\pi}{3}}+e^{-in\frac{\pi}{3}}\\
&=2\cos\left(n\frac{\pi}{3}\right)
\end{align*}
and the claim (11) follows.

> We conclude from (9) and (11)
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} &{n-k\choose k}\frac {(-1)^k}{n-k}=\frac{2}{n}\cos\left(n\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\qquad\qquad n\geq 1
> \end{align*}
>
> Finally, note that
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{2}{n}\cos\left(n\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{2}{n}(-1)^n&n\equiv 0 \pmod{3}\\
> \frac{1}{n}(-1)^{n-1}&otherwise
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>    which proves that (1) is valid.

Comment: Do you mean $n \equiv 0 \ (\text{mod } 3)$? This answer is really cool.

Comment: @Axoren: Yes. Typo corrected, thanks.